# Scrapy follow javascript input button

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have following input's on the page:

```
<input name="ct99" value="" id="ct99" class="GetData" type="submit">
<input name="ct92" value="" id="ct92" class="GetData" type="submit">
<input name="ct87" value="" id="ct87" class="GetData" type="submit">
```

class GetData display some click-able icon. When click on it new page is opened. Some JavaScript taking care of it. How can I follow this?

I'm already try code below just to see if scrapy follow inputs, but without success.

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)

    links = sel.xpath("//input[@class='GetData']").extract()
    for data in links:
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,
            formdata={}, callback=self.after_click)


def after_click(self, response):
    url = response.url
    print '\nURL', url
```

Comment: you need pass form url in next request, do you have all html?

Comment: nope, I have nothing more then these input fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two common ways to approach the problem:

- using browser developer tools (Network tab), inspect the requests sent when you click a particular button and then simulate this request using `scrapy.Request` or `scrapy.FormRequest`
- automate a browser using [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/): locate the button and click it, then grab the `.page_source` and instantiate a `Selector` instance, see samples here:

  - [Scrapy with Selenium crawling but not scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585068/scrapy-with-selenium-crawling-but-not-scraping)
  - [How to use selenium along with scrapy to automate the process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101973/how-to-use-selenium-along-with-scrapy-to-automate-the-process)

Comment: Excellent answer thank you. I use selenium, but how to iterate over inputs? I have error TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable links = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='GetData']")

Comment: @Goran sure, use `find_elements_by_xpath` (watch the `s`).

Comment: I'm use self.driver = webdriver.Firefox() but it close with error "StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up" Any hint?

Comment: @Goran please consider making a separate question and provide as many details as you can. Thank you!