# Scrapy with java content on a web server

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'd like to scrape content from a site which apparently uses a javascript to generate the tables (the site is oddsportal.com).

I see that Scrapy can't load dynamic content, i read selenium could handle it but i'm planning to use a web server.

Is there a way i can parse this site or get the dynamic request and parse it using scrapy?

For example i'd like to import the full table from this page with the headers, match name and odds

http://www.oddsportal.com/matches/handball/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you have a constraint that you don't have a real display. You can still go with selenium - there is a headless [`PhantomJS` browser](http://phantomjs.org/) that can be automated, there is an option to work in a [virtual display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb), and you can use a *remote selenium server* or [`docker-selenium`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium).

There are multiple examples on how to combine selenium and scrapy, for instance:

- [selenium with scrapy for dynamic page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page)
- [Scrapy with Selenium crawling but not scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27585068/771848)

---

And, also check if [`scrapy-splash`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapy-splash) middleware would be enough for your use case.

Comment: So the easiest choice would be Scrapy+PhantomJS+Selenium?

Comment: @GGA yup, though, I would first start with trying out scrapy-splash, and then PhantomJS.

Comment: Thanks i'll try, scrapy-splash alone would be enough for a simple one page request?

Comment: @GGA basically, it would pass the page through the standalone js engine. Sometimes it's enough to tackle the dynamic page parsing. `PhantomJS` though is the most straight-forward approach here involving less setup.

Comment: How would i use shell and docker for scrapy-splash on a server?

Comment: @GGA glad to see you are actually trying out splash. Please elaborate it into a separate question providing all the necessary details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For sites with dynamic content through AJAX and Javascript, I have used [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). It doesn't require open a browser because it's in itself a fully scriptable web browser. PhantomJS is fast and includes native support for various web standards as DOM handling, CSS selector, JSON and Canvas.

If you aren't a JavaScript Ninja, You should look [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/), it is written over PhantomJS. It eases the process of defining a full navigation scenario and provides useful high-level functions.

Here an example about how CasperJS works:

[CasperJs and Jquery with chained Selects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283908/casperjs-and-jquery-with-chained-selects/16300933#16300933)